# Как расставить кавычки, чтобы вставить в php код html разметку c php кодом внутри?

Tags: php, html

Переделываю на скорую руку школьный проект и в php код нужно вставить html разметку с php кодом внутри. Запутался с кавычками. Вот то, что нужно вставить в php код:

```
$txt = "<form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Инвентарь</strong></td>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Метод</strong></td>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Номер род. кат.</strong></td>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Уровень</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo '<select name="inv_name">';
            $query = mysqli_query($link,'select * from inventory');
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query))
                    while($inv = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                            echo '<option value="'.$inv["id_inventory"].'">'.$inv["name"].'</option>';
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </td>
            <td><input name='method_name' type='text' id='method_name'></td>
            <td><input name='method_pid' type='text' id='method_pid'></td>
            <td><input name='method_level' type='text' id='method_level'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='4' style='text-align: center'><input type='submit' value='Добавить запись'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";
```

Comment: Никогда не мешайте `HTML` и `PHP`! Делите логику и представление наконец, чай динозавры уже вымерли.

Comment: Или хотя бы сначала создайте контент со списком и вставьте переменной в `HTML`. И используйте `HEREDOC` синтаксис - это уберёт проблемы с кавычками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы не путаться с ковычками, надо отделить логику и представление.

1. Можно использовать хороший шаблонизатор(Twig например).
2. Можно построить свой код так что бы получение данных и вывод не были в одном месте.
3. В вашем примере самый простой и быстрый споособ пользоваться функциями форматирования.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
<?php 
    // Создаём выподающий список
    $dropDown = '<select name="inv_name">';
    $query = mysqli_query($link,'select * from inventory');
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
        while($inv = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $dropDown .= sprintf(
                '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
                $inv["id_inventory"],
                $inv["id_inventory"]
            );
        }
    }

    $dropDown .= '</select>';

    // Вставляем его в форму.
    $txt = sprintf("<form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Инвентарь</strong></td>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Метод</strong></td>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Номер род. кат.</strong</td>
            <td style='text-align: center'><strong>Уровень</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
            <td><input name='method_name' type='text' id='method_name'></td>
            <td><input name='method_pid' type='text' id='method_pid'></td>
            <td><input name='method_level' type='text' id='method_level'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='4' style='text-align: center'><input type='submit' value='Добавить запись'></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>",
      $dropDown
    );
```

Comment: Вместо поля со списком показывает просто 0

Comment: Какое значение у $dropDown?

Comment: @unit С Javascript не переключился:) поправил пример поменял "+" на ".".

Comment: Разобрался! Спасибо!

Comment: А зависимые поля со списком делать по такому же принципу?

Comment: @unit Можно и так. Привидите пример того что вы хотите. Тогда смогу подсказать.

Comment: Берём из таблицы с иерархией значения, в первом поле со списком выбираем верхнюю иерархию, во втором поле со списком, в зависимости от того, что было выбрано в первом, выбираем уже нужную запись.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40952/discussion-between-e-p-and-unit).

Comment: Взять хотя бы этот пример и представить что у этой таблицы есть поле родительской категории и два селекта.

Answer (score 0):

'
se lect name="' . 'inv_name' . '">';
.$inv["' . 'name' . '"]

По идее так (точки окружены одинарными)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно экранировать внутренние двойные кавычки, таким образом:

```
\"
```

Comment: Ругается на эту строчку:
echo '<option value=\"'.$inv[\"id_inventory\"].'\">'.$inv[\"name\"].'</option>';

Не ожидалось string после: [
Ожидалось: identifier, variable, NUM_STRING, define

Comment: там где переменные php сделайте внутри одинарные кавычки, а экранировать нужно оставшиеся в html двойные кавычки

Comment: В таком сложном примере на войну с ковычками уйдет больше ремени чем если переписать с функциями форматирования.

Comment: @E_p, да я не против, что это кривота вставлять php через html :) но всякое бывает, может пригодится